# why doesnot the warning information show up in matlab ?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I am using Matlab 2014b on Ubuntu 14.04. However, when there is one error in my code, Matlab will show the error using one red underline. And move our cursor to the red line and the error information will show. However, when I moved my cursor to the red line, it just gave me one blank pop-up window. No message is given. Could any one help me solve this issue ? 
[image]

Comment: What is the name of your file? Is it also called `compute_interactions_c`?

Comment: yes. but I want to know why the warning message does not show but only one blank pop-up.

Comment: I'm not sure.  It may be a bug with the Linux version of MATLAB.  I've never seen it before.  Perhaps you should contact MathWorks instead.

Comment: @tqjustc are you using Gnome? this is an issue with gnome-shell, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165093/blank-matlab-code-tooltips-in-gnome-3-debian-jessie